# Table filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have table with date from json file. The definition for `tr` element is:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="map in collection | filter:myFilter">
```

and also I have 3 buttons to filter the data:

```
<button ng-click="myFilter = {city: 'lodz'}">Łódź</button>
<button ng-click="myFilter = {city: 'rome'}">Rome</button>
<button ng-click="myFilter = {city: 'ny'}">New York</button>
```

By default in table there are all the data from json file. What I want to achieve is the table ware empty before select filter.

Comment: Then you can override the current filter behaviour to add your own behaviour...

Comment: Add another button for clearing the filter.  Something like `<button ng-click="myFilter = {}">Reset Filter</button>`

Comment: @ryanyuyu the only reason I wouldn't do that is it could become unintuitive to the user

Comment: But I don't want to click on button, I want have empty table by default.

Comment: So do my option then...

Comment: Initialize `myFilter = {}`, and it will be like that by default.

Answer (score 0):

So all you have to do is override the angular `filter`, checkout my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ji6vxam3wrfX47WRMSJ1?p=preview)

```
function customFilter($filter) {
  return function (array, expression, comparator) {
    if (isEmpty(expression)){
      return [];
    } else{
      return $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator);
    }
  };
}


function isEmpty(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
          return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

The first function is the filter, that merely wraps the angular one. The second function checks if an object is empty!

Answer (score 0):

> By default in table there are all the data from json file. What I want
>   to achieve is the table ware empty before select filter.

Since you do NOT want any data when the table is loaded, you can have something like this in your table's ng-init function.

```
<table ng-init="myFilter = {}">
</table>
```

Comment: I checked it. If filter is defined as `myFiler ={}` it means the same as if ther was no filer, so the table shows all the data. I also checked something like this:
`<table ng-init="myFilter = {city:'nothing'}">` then table is empty but buttons does not work.

Comment: Ok I get it!
I set `ng-init="myFilter = {city: null}"` but in the same element as ng-app is declared. In Table element that is not work.